# React Native Using stacknavigator and tabnavigator error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I want to proceed as follows

StackNavigator -> TabNavigator -> StackNavigator

Clicking the button on the screen moves to the tabbed screen and pressing the button on the tabbed screen moves to the other tabless screen.

**Navigator.js**

```
const SignUpScene = createStackNavigator({
 SignUp: {screen: SignUp},
}, ...

const SigninScene = createStackNavigator({
 HomeUI: {screen: HomeUI},
 TopTab: {screen: TopTab},
 Screen1: {screen: Screen1},
 SignUpScene: {screen: SignUpScene},
}, ...

const HomeScene = createStackNavigator({
 SigninScene: {screen: SigninScene},
}, ...

export default class Navigator extends Component {
 render() {
  return(
   <HomeScene />
  );
 }
}
```

**HomeUI.js**

```
render() {
 const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
 return (
  <View>
   <Image... />
   <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
     ...
     opPress={() => navigate("TopTab")}>
     <Text> button1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
     ...
     onPress={() => navigate("Screen1")}>
     <Text> button2 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  </View>
 )}
```

**TopTab.js**

```
export default TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
 Tab1: {
  screen: Tab1,
  navigationOptions: {...}
 },
 Tab2: {
  screen: Tab2,
  navigationOptions: {...}
 }
})
```

**Tab1.js**

```
render() {
 const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
 return(
  ...
  <view>
   <Button
    onPress={() => navigate("SignUpScene")} />
    ...
  </View> 
  ...
 )}
```

The following error occurs:

> undefined is not an object ('this.props.navigation.navigate')

How do I resolve it?

Can I see stacks stacked in stacknavigator?

I want to debug

Comment: Can't you find answer to your question in this post maybe? https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1979

Comment: this not solved